# How do you detect Workout start / stop with HealthKit?

Tags: ios, healthkit

I'm looking for a way to detect workout detect / stop using HealthKit and it seems there is no way to detect it.

In Android you get "ACTION_SESSION_START" and "ACTION_SESSION_END" for sessions.

Has anyone tried detecting workout start / stop?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Are you trying to detect when another application on watchOS? There is no API for that. What are you trying to do with that information?

Comment: @Allan I'm creating a test app for HealthKit and wanted to know if there is any way to "listen" or "query" the status change of workout status whether it is from another application or from Apple Watch. Basically to log "Any Workout start" or "Any Workout stop" with the test app. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I don't see this functionality exposed in the `HKWorkout` documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit/hkworkout

Comment: [This](https://www.raywenderlich.com/89733/healthkit-tutorial-with-swift-workouts) is a wonderful tutorial and should answer your question.

Comment: @Dershowitz123 that tutorial shows how to save workouts, not detect them.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking you could **detect** events. Not **save** a workout.

In HealthKit you can create workout events. Therefore you could theoretically code something to detect `pause`/`resume` events.

Create a running workout that goes for ___ time.

```
let finish = NSDate() // Now  
let start = finish.dateByAddingTimeInterval(0000) // workout time

let workout = HKWorkout(activityType: .Running, startDate: start, endDate: finish)
```

Create `Pause` (stop) and `Resume` (start) events.

```
let workoutEvents: [HKWorkoutEvent] = [  
HKWorkoutEvent(type: .Pause, date: startDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(000)),
HKWorkoutEvent(type: .Resume, date: startDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(000))
]
```

Then you need to alter the creation of the `HKWorkout` object to use the more complex constructor, which allows you to include `workoutEvents`.

```
let workout = HKWorkout(  
activityType: .Running
startDate: start,
endDate: end,
workoutEvents: workoutEvents,
device: nil,
metadata: nil
)
```

At this point you would normally pass the workout to `HKHealthStore.saveObject` to save it like this.

```
healthStore.saveObject(workout) { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

if success {
    // Workout was saved
}
else {
    // Workout was not saved
}
}
```

### But

in your case you **don't want to save**. You want to **detect events**. could have a switch statement that could detect a `Pause` or `Resume`.

I'm not sure about the specific `dateByAddingTimeInterval` values you would want but it's definitely something you could experiment with using zero values maybe? Because technically `00` is still an event.

Workout events toggle a workout object between an active and an inactive state. You could create a method `detectWorkoutEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for observing workouts being recorded by another app.